# out put of dataset column unique id including comma separated to input of stored procedure pls check image

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, dataset, c#-3.0

```
public DataSet GetDataReviewer_N(int Status, string UniqueID, 
   string ReviewerUID, string SearchReviewerUID,
   string Period, string cass, int FirstRec, 
   int LastRec, string searchUniqueID)
{

    DbCommand dbcGetVariableDetails = dbITSecurity.GetStoredProcCommand("uid_get_data_reviewer_n_test2");
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_Status", DbType.Int32, Status);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_Unique_ID", DbType.String, UniqueID);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_SearchUniqueID", DbType.String, searchUniqueID);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_ReviewerUID", DbType.String, ReviewerUID);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_SelectReviewer", DbType.String, SearchReviewerUID);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_Period", DbType.String, Period);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_cass", DbType.String, cass);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_First", DbType.Int32, FirstRec);
    dbITSecurity.AddInParameter(dbcGetVariableDetails, "p_Last", DbType.Int32, LastRec);
    OracleParameter cursor = new OracleParameter("cur_out", OracleType.Cursor);

    cursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    dbcGetVariableDetails.Parameters.Add(cursor);

    DataSet dsGetVariableDetails = dbITSecurity.ExecuteDataSet(dbcGetVariableDetails);
    return (dsGetVariableDetails);

}
```

above code gives dataset ,i wants one column unique id from dataset and iterate as comma separated values and pass to oracle stored procedure.please see below image .
[image]

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Chetan Ranpariya  edited subject

Comment: Please don't use embedded images to explain your problem. Many people cannot access image dump sites, so it will make it less likely you get a timely and helpful answer. Also, if you want to attract a particular user's attention who need to prefix their name with `@`

Comment: Try following :             string[] values = dsGetVariableDetails.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Column Name")).Distinct().ToArray();
            string csv = string.Join(",", values);